# I need to loop in the array and generate new document for each filter in Level array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to loop in the array but i cant fix it can someone help
As of this it works fine the problem is i want to do multiple documents at once but this only ges my first value and ignores the rest

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt

# Open the Word template

document = Document('Kontrata.docx')

# Set the font and size for the document

font = document.styles\['Normal'\].font
font.name = 'Times New Roman'
font.size = Pt(9)

# List of values to filter on

filter_values = \["P-07740", "P-15539", "P-17139"\]

# Loop through each value in the list

for value in filter_values:
\# Read in the Excel file and filter the data based on LEVEL = value
df = pd.read_excel("./Test.xlsx", sheet_name="Per kontrate")
df_filtered = df\[df\['LEVEL'\] == value\]

# Get the data from the filtered dataframe for the corresponding level

emri_mbiemri = f"{df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\['Emri'\]} {df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\['Mbiemri'\]}"
adresa = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\['Adresa'\]
nr_personal = str(df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\["ID NUMBER"\])
vendi_qyteti = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\['Vendi/Qyteti'\]
kualifikim = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\['Kualifikim'\]
pozita = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\["Titulli Aktual"\]
detyrat = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\["Detyrat e punes"\]
pika = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\["Nr I pikes"\]
rruga = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\["Rruga"\]
fkontrata = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\["Fillimi I\\nkontrates"\]
mkontrata = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\["Nenshkrimi I\\nkontrates"\]

# Open the Word template

document = Document('Kontrata.docx')

# Set the font and size for the document

font = document.styles\['Normal'\].font
font.name = 'Times New Roman'
font.size = Pt(9)

# Loop through each paragraph in the document

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
\# Replace the placeholders with the corresponding data value
if '{{emri_mbiemri}}' in paragraph.text:
paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{emri_mbiemri}}', emri_mbiemri)
if '{{adresa}}' in paragraph.text:
paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{adresa}}', adresa)
if '{{nr_personal}}' in paragraph.text:
paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{nr_personal}}', nr_personal)
if '{{vendi_qyteti}}' in paragraph.text:
paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{vendi_qyteti}}', vendi_qyteti)
if '{{kualifikim}}' in paragraph.text:
paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{kualifikim}}', kualifikim)
if '{{pozita}}' in paragraph.text:
paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{pozita}}', pozita)
if '{{detyrat}}' in paragraph.text:
paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{detyrat}}', detyrat)
if '{{pika}}' in paragraph.text:
paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{pika}}', pika)
if '{{vendi}}' in paragraph.text:
paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{vendi}}', vendi_qyteti)
if '{{rruga}}' in paragraph.text:
paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{rruga}}', rruga)
if '{{fkontrata}}' in paragraph.text:
paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{fkontrata}}', fkontrata)
if '{{mkontrata}}' in paragraph.text:
paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{mkontrata}}', mkontrata)
\# Set the alignment for the paragraphs

# Loop through each table in the document

for table in document.tables:
\# Loop through each row in the table
for row in table.rows:
\# Loop through each cell in the row
for cell in row.cells:
\# Replace the placeholder text with the corresponding data value
if '{{emri_mbiemri}}' in cell.text:
cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{emri_mbiemri}}', emri_mbiemri)
if '{{adresa}}' in cell.text:
cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{adresa}}', adresa)
if '{{nr_personal}}' in cell.text:
cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{nr_personal}}', nr_personal)
if '{{vendi_qyteti}}' in cell.text:
cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{vendi_qyteti}}', vendi_qyteti)
if '{{kualifikim}}' in cell.text:
cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{kualifikim}}', kualifikim)
if '{{pozita}}' in cell.text:
cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{pozita}}', pozita)
if '{{detyrat}}' in cell.text:
cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{detyrat}}', detyrat)
if '{{pika}}' in cell.text:
cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{pika}}', pika)
if '{{vendi}}' in cell.text:
cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{vendi}}', vendi_qyteti)
if '{{rruga}}' in cell.text:
cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{rruga}}', rruga)
if '{{fkontrata}}' in cell.text:
cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{fkontrata}}', fkontrata)
if '{{mkontrata}}' in cell.text:
cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{mkontrata}}', mkontrata)
\# Set the alignment for the cells

# Save the populated document as a new file

document.save(f"{emri_mbiemri}.docx")
```

I need to loop in the array but i cant fix it can someone help
As of this it works fine the problem is i want to do multiple documents at once but this only ges my first value and ignores the rest

Comment: Ummm sorry, can you clarify what "array" you are referring to? Are you trying to say you are attempting to find the matches for each filter across multiple documents? (Like `[filters] in <document> for document in [list of documents]`)?

Comment: Why are there all those backslashes in the code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.